# Add Class in Library of Robot Framework

Tags: python, class, testing, robotframework, keyword

I want to add a class in the library of robot framework but it does not work.
I create a simple test to describe my issue.

---

```
Robot script: helloworld.robot  
*** Settings ***    
Library         Library.py

*** Test Cases ***    
Hello World     
      ${x} =     Print Hello World      
         log to console          ${x}
```

---

Library scirpt: Library.py

```
class Hello_World(object):    
      def print_Hello_World():         
            return "Hello World"
```

---

Output of terminal:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JmuqZ.png)

---

I dont understand why I get an error that no keyword found.

The script works without the class, but I need to add classes for further tests.

I would be happy if someone could take a look at my problem.

Best
psad

Comment: Please don't link error messages as images, this makes it harder for everyone (including search indexing); also, use code block to format the corresponding section.

Answer (score 1):

From the [user guide](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#library-name):

> The name of a test library that is used when a library is imported is the same as the name of the module or class implementing it.

And:

> Python classes are always inside a module. If the name of a class implementing a library is the same as the name of the module, Robot Framework allows dropping the class name when importing the library.
> ...
> If the module name and class name are different, libraries must be taken into use using both module and class names, such as mymodule.MyLibrary or parent.submodule.MyLib.

So rename the class to be the same as the file it's in, or provide the class name when importing.

Comment: Thanks Todor for your help. When I change the name of the class as the file it works.
I tried also to provide the class name but it doesnt work. For my example above I typed: 
Library    Hello_World.Library

Comment: For the format `Library    Library.Hello_World` to work, the Library.py file has to be in a directory, which is in the pythonpath (see the error when you try to run it like this, it should've printed something similar).